# Performance Tab in Lightning Inspector

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I'm trying to understand the performance bottle necks of my lightning component using Salesforce Lightning Inspector (https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/02/introducing-salesforce-lightning-inspector.html).

I see "markup://aura:text" taking around 70-80% of the performance, and I'm trying to understand what is this about!? Any suggestions/pointers are most welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to know without knowing more about your code. Can you tell us what you're trying to do? Is aura:text taking a long time? or are just 70-80% of your components aura:text?

Answer (score 2):

When you see "markup://aura:text" taking a lot of time in most cases it means there is a call to backend at that time.

[image: Lightning Inspector Performance Tab]

If you open "Transactions Tab" in Lightning Inspector you will see that http-request takes that time

[image: Lightning Inspector Transactions Tab]

If you transfer a lot of data (several MBs) from Apex to Lightning that might be the bottleneck.